# Does a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism of a punctured surface possess infinitely many periodic points?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems, surfaces

In [A Primer on Mapping Class Groups](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~bgabi/Farb%20Magalit%20January%202011%20version.pdf) by Farb and Margalit theorem 14.19 implies that every pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism $f:S \rightarrow S$ on a compact surface $S$ possesses infinitely many periodic points. I was wondering if this result is also true for compact Surfaces with a finite number of interior points removed (e.g. A sphere with a finite number of punctures).

Does anyone have a reference?

Comment: In the case where the surface $M$ is a sphere $S^2$ with finitely many punctures and the homeomorphism $f$ leaves the punctures fixed (i.e. it can be extended to a homeomorphism $S^2 \rightarrow S^2$) my idea would be to extend $f$ to the sphere. It should be possible to obtain a singular foliation on $S^2$ by adding 1-pronged singularities at the punctures. Since we are not changing anything substantial the extended homeomorphism should still be pseudo-Anosov. Then we are in the compact case and the existence of infinitely many periodic points carries over to $f$ on the punctured surface.

Comment: It certainly does for disc with finite number of punctures. http://people.clas.ufl.edu/boyland/files/stir.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put a prong singularity at each puncture, allowing any number of prongs $\ge 1$, then the proof of infinitely many periodic points (in fact, their denseness) goes through with no changes: construct a Markov partition in exactly the same manner, and then apply symbolic dynamics.